# Why I can't pass two chars as function arguments in C?

Tags: c, function, char

I have a function:

```
int get_symbol(tab *tp, FILE *fp, char delim)
```

and I call it like this:

```
get_symbol(tp, fp, ';')
```

I always have it declared in the header as:

```
int get_symbol(tab *, FILE *, char);
```

No this all works fine, I can execute the code in the function and the delim is set.
But if I try to add one more char to the function's signature like:

```
int get_symbol(tab *tp, FILE *fp, char delim1, char delim2)
```

The function stops executing. Why would that be?

Comment: This should work, at least from what you posted. Can you elaborate the issue further? How exactly does "stops executing" look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops executing" ?

Comment: You have a bug in your code. Show the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should have :

```
int get_symbol(tab *tp, FILE *fp, char delim1, char delim2)
{
blah blah;
return 1;
}
...
...

get_symbol(tp, fp, ';','?')
```

do You?

Answer (score 1):

OK, there's not enough information here, so I'm going to make a wild stab at an answer.

You're using a C++ compiler, and don't have warning levels set very high. You've changed the prototype for the function, but you've not changed the arguments when you call it. The C++ compiler is treating these as different functions due to [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading), and so is not calling the right one.

This may be way off what's happening. If it is, give us something more to go on….

Answer (score 0):

As a guess at what "stops executing" could mean, did you update the signature in the header file as well?

Comment: What does "stops executing" mean then? You will need to post the code for the function and describe what you expect to happen.